# django-sendgrid-v5 Everything seems to work fine but mails don't get delivered

Tags: python, django, sendgrid

I'm using the [django-sendgrid-v5](https://pypi.org/project/django-sendgrid-v5/) package to send mails in django. Everything works fine but the mail never reaches to the inbox, neither spam.
Here are my current configurations:

`.env` file:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND='sendgrid_backend.SendgridBackend' 
SENDGRID_API_KEY='SG.the_rest_of_the_api_key'
```

`settings.py` file:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = env('EMAIL_BACKEND')
SENDGRID_API_KEY = env('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
SENDGRID_SANDBOX_MODE_IN_DEBUG=False
```

and my mail function:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail( mail_subject, message, 'noreply.cpsb@nyeri.go.ke', [to_email], fail_silently=False )
```

On sending the email, I get no error, but still the mail doesn't get delivered.
What could I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally worked it through. The problem was Sender Authentication, Which By the way is not very elaborate in the documentation.

After generating an API key you're supposed to add some CNAME records to your DNS service provider for sendgrid to be authenticated to send emails.

With a lot of help from [This medium article](https://medium.com/@info_93479/how-to-get-free-domain-email-with-django-and-sendgrid-96c1e0b1b360)

So the problem was not on the code.